# Javascript Timer To UTC Depends on Computer Time?

Tags: javascript, client, server-side, countdown, utc

So this script (credit to http://www.rmkwebdesign.com/Countdown_Timers/Repeating_Daily_Timer.html), is basically a Javascript daily countdown. I changed the getDate variables to getUTCDate, but it still isn't UTC and depends on client clock. How do I fix this, and make it not depend on the client side computer time so the countdown will not display incorrectly if clients computer time is wrong?? Thanks.

Here's the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var current = "Test";

var startHour = 0;

var startMinute = 0;

var endHour = 23;

var endMinute = 55;

var tz = 0;

var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

 if (startMinute < 10){startMinute = "0" + startMinute;}

function countdown()
{
var today=new Date();
var todayy=today.getYear();
if (todayy < 1000) 
{todayy += 1900;}

var todaym = today.getUTCMonth();
var todayd = today.getUTCDate();
var todayh = today.getUTCHours();
var todaymin = today.getUTCMinutes();
var todaysec = today.getUTCSeconds();

// add a zero in front of numbers<10
todaymin = checkTime(todaymin);
todaysec = checkTime(todaysec);

var startString = parseInt(startHour + "" + startMinute + "00");

var nowString1 = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec;
var nowString = Date.parse(nowString1) + (tz*1000*60*60);
var nowTime = parseInt(todayh + "" + todaymin + "" + todaysec);

var endString1 = (montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + endHour + ":" + endMinute);
var endString = Date.parse(endString1) - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * (1000*60));

var dd = endString - nowString;
var dday = Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
var dhour = Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
var dmin = Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
var dsec = Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

if ((dhour <= 0 && dmin <= 0 && dsec <= 0) || (nowTime < startString))
{
    document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML = current;
    document.getElementById('count2').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('count2').style.width = "390px";
    document.getElementById('dhour').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dmin').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dsec').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('hours').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('minutes').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('seconds').style.display = "none";
    setTimeout("countdown()",500);
    return;
}

else
{
    document.getElementById('count2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dhour').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('dmin').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('dsec').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('hours').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('minutes').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('seconds').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML = dhour;
    document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML = dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML = dsec;
    setTimeout("countdown()",500);
}

if (dhour < 2 || (dhour == 2 && dmin == 0 && dsec == 0))
{
    document.getElementById('dhour').style.color = "yellow";
    document.getElementById('dmin').style.color = "yellow";
    document.getElementById('dsec').style.color = "yellow";
}

if (dhour < 1 || (dhour == 1 && dmin == 0 && dsec == 0))
{
    document.getElementById('dhour').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('dmin').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('dsec').style.color = "red";
}
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution I can think about is that you send your client the amount of seconds the timer will go on instead of a timestamp, but It could be inaccurate due to HTTP transfer latency.